# Struts 2.3.14 junit test

Tags: java, struts2, junit4, struts2-junit-plugin

I'm using Struts 2.3.14 for my application... I need some unit test in my application... so I'm using junit4... but when I use `ActionProxy` in my test, it will show `NullPointerException`...

**my test code is:**

```
ActionProxy proxy=getActionProxy("/customize/saveRewards");
    SaveRewardsPlus rewards=(SaveRewardsPlus)proxy.getAction();
    request.setParameter("list[0].img_id", "1");        
    request.setParameter("list[0].tag", "Test Tag");
    request.setParameter("list[0].desc", "Test Desc");        
    String result=proxy.execute();        
    assertEquals("success", result);
```

**and my Action Class is:**

```
private List<RewardsBean> list;    

public String execute() {
    try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(CONSTR, USER, PWD);
        for (RewardsBean rb : list) {
            sql = "update rewards set tag=?,description=? where img_id=?";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, rb.getTag());
            ps.setString(2, rb.getDesc());
            ps.setInt(3, rb.getImg_id());
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}

/**
 * @return the list
 */
public List<RewardsBean> getList() {
    return list;
}
```

How can i send request to the action class and how to use `ActionProxy`...
Please Help me to Improve.....
Thankyou in advance......

**my struts.xml file is given below.....**

```
<struts>
  <!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
  <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="addRewards" class="com.customize.rewards.AddRewards">
       <result name="success">index.jsp</result>
    </action>
  </package>
  <include file="addrewards/struts-addrewards.xml"></include>
  <include file="customize/struts-customize.xml"></include>
</struts>
```

**and my imported xml file is given below....**

```
<struts>
    <package name="customize" namespace="/customize" extends="struts-default">
        <!--<action name="viewRewards" class="com.customize.rewards.ViewRewards">
            <result>/customizeRewards/viewRewards.jsp</result>
        </action>        -->
        <!-- New Rewards-->
        <action name="viewRewards" class="com.customize.rewards.ViewRewards">
            <result>/customizeRewards/viewRewardsPlus.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="saveRewards" class="com.customize.rewards.SaveRewardsPlus"> 
            <result name="success" type="redirect">viewRewards</result>           
        </action>
        <!--/New Rewards-->
       <!-- <action name="saveRewards" class="com.customize.rewards.SaveRewards"> 
            <result name="success" type="redirect">viewRewards</result>           
        </action>-->
        <action name="deleteRewards" class="com.customize.rewards.DeleteRewards">
            <result name="success" type="redirect">viewRewards</result>
        </action>
        <action name="addRewards" class="com.customize.rewards.AddRewards">
            <result name="success" type="redirect">viewRewards</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**my stacktrace....**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at
org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase.getActionProxy(StrutsTestCase.java:130) at 
com.customize.rewards.SaveRewardsPlusTest.testExecute(SaveRewardsPlusTest.java:4‌​9) 
Testsuite: com.customize.rewards.SaveRewardsTest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `junit4`, so the correct test case class to use in this case would be `StrutsJUnit4TestCase`. It has annotations required to run on start up to init mock objects necessary to run your code. Particular getting action proxy requires the mock `request`.