# Unit testing Struts 2 actions

Tags: java, junit, struts2

Guys I need to figure out a way to unit test our legacy code in our enterprise application which uses struts 2.

I can't seem to figure it out, I tried using the JUnit plugin the same way used in their website https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/unit-testing.html but I can't seem to make it work.. didn't find any other useful resources(most of it is very outdated).

I am getting this stack trace when trying to run the test:

```
javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be created

    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:311)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:267)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:127)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:1060)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:198)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:166)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:957)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:463)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:496)
    at org.apache.struts2.util.StrutsTestCaseHelper.initDispatcher(StrutsTestCaseHelper.java:44)
    at org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase.initDispatcher(StrutsTestCase.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase.setUp(StrutsTestCase.java:216)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:139)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be created
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:308)
    ... 27 more
```

Is this happening because of a jar/dependency conflict?

Comment: Make sure you are using correct [test case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16651597/573032).

Comment: @Roman C Yeah I tried that as well but still facing the same exception `javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be created
`

Comment: The exception comes from Java side. You will probably end up with correct Java version.